# Prove that for every $x \in[0,1]$, there exists $c\in[0,1]$ such that $f(c)=1-f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q: Let $f:[0,1]\longrightarrow \Bbb R$ be a continuously function such that
$$m\leq f(x)\leq M, m+M=1 (m:\text{minimum of} f(x), M:\text{maximum of} f(x) )$$
Prove that for every $x \in[0,1]$, there exists  $c\in[0,1]$ such that $f(c)=1-f(x)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $f([0,1]) = [m,M]$, and $m+M=1$. Hence if we let $\phi(x) = 1-f(x)$, we have $\phi([0,1]) = [1-M,1-m] = [m,M]$.

Hence $f([0,1]) = \phi([0,1])$.

It should be straightforward to finish from here.

Answer (score 2):

Note that, $m= 1-M \le 1-f(x) \le 1-m =M$, Now apply Intermediate Value theorem to get $c\in [0,1]$ st $f(c)=1-f(x)$